# Long long int Overflow

Tags: c++, overflow

This below is my code for adding 4 elements of vector arr and then printing the min-sum and the max-sum. This below is my code. Though after using unsigned long long of which the range is **0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615** to be precise. I am getting an integer overflow answer when the test case is **256741038 623958417 467905213 714532089 938071625**. According to me, the answer should be in the limit of u-l-l. Please help me to better understand the cause.

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {
vector<int> A;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    unsigned long long int ans=0;
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
        if(i==j)    continue;
        else    ans+=arr[j];
    }
    A.push_back(ans);
}
sort(A.begin(), A.end());
cout<<A[0]<<" "<<A[4];
}
```

Comment: Print `sizeof(unsigned long long)`. You will get a number N. The overflow will occur at `input = 2^(8*N)`.

Answer (score 3):

`vector<int> A;` is a vector of ints. When you `A.push_back(ans);`, `ans` gets converted to `int`, which results in overflow.

Just changing the declaration of `A` to `vector<unsigned long long int> A;` fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of "issues" with this code, I'd suggest to make a few changes:

1. passing vector by value is quite expensive, it's better to pass by
   reference, and since your don't mutate the input vector, so make it
   const. `void miniMaxSum(const std::vector<int>& arr)`
2. the two level of loops is Log(N^2) complexity, you can calculate total sum of `arr`, and then go over `arr` again and subtract each
   element from the total sum to get your answer.
3. since you are only interested in min_sum and max_sum, you can avoid the expensive sorting at the end.
4. since your inputs are `int`s, you'd not use unsigned int to hold results, so that your code will also work for negative integers as
   input.
5. do not hard code/assume your input vector always contains 5 elements, use `arr.size()` instead.

The following is the modified code, which is in Log(N) complexity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

void miniMaxSum(const std::vector<int>& arr) {
    vector<int64_t> A;
    int64_t sum = std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0ull);
    int64_t min_sum = LLONG_MAX;
    int64_t max_sum = LLONG_MIN;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
        int64_t v = sum - arr[i];
        if (v < min_sum) min_sum = v;
        if (v > max_sum) max_sum = v;
    }
    cout<<min_sum<<" "<<max_sum;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> a{256741038, 623958417, 467905213, 714532089, 938071625};
    miniMaxSum(a);
    return 0;
}
```